# When to use Pragma Pure/Preelaborate

Tags: ada, pragma, elaboration

Is there a set of general rules/guidelines that can help to understand when to prefer `pragma Pure`, `pragma Preelaborate`, or something else entirely? The rules and definitions presented in the [standard (Ada 2012)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-10-2-1.html), are a little heavy-going and I'd be grateful to read something that's a little more clear and geared towards the average case.

If I wanted to be thorough without fully understanding the "why" of it, can I simply try:

- Mark the package spec with `pragma Pure;`
- If it doesn't compile, try `pragma Preelaborate;`
- If that fails, then I've done something tricky and either need to `pragma Elaborate` units on a `with`-by-`with` basis, or rethink the package layout.

While this *might* work (does it?), because it's recommended to mark a package as Pure whenever possible (likewise with Preelaborate), however it seems a bit brain damaged and I'd prefer to understand the process a bit better.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

#### `pragma Pure`

You should use this on any package which does not have an internal state. It tells the user of the package that calls to any subprograms cannot have side effects, because there is no internal state they could change. So a function declared at library level inside a pure package will always return the same result when called with the same parameters.

The Ada implementation is allowed to cache return values of functions of a pure package, and to omit calls to subroutines if their return values won't be used because of these requirements. However, you can violate the constraints by calling imported subroutines (e.g. from a C library) inside your pure package (these may change some internal state which the Ada compiler doesn't know of). If you're evil, you can even import Ada subroutines from other parts of the software with `pragma Import` to bypass the requirements of `pragma Pure`. Needless to say: If you're doing anything like this, don't use `pragma Pure`.

**Edit:** To clarify the circumstances when calls may be omitted, let me quote the [ARM](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/95lrm/ARM_HTML/RM-10-2-1.html):

> If a library unit is declared pure, then the implementation is permitted to omit a call on a library-level subprogram of the library unit if the results are not needed after the call. Similarly, it may omit such a call and simply reuse the results produced by an earlier call on the same subprogram, provided that none of the parameters are of a limited type, and the addresses and values of all by-reference actual parameters, and the values of all by-copy-in actual parameters, are the same as they were at the earlier call. This permission applies even if the subprogram produces other side effects when called.

GNAT, for example, additionally defines that any subroutines that take a parameter of type `System.Address` or a type derived from it are not considered pure even if they are defined in a pure package, because the location the address points to may be altered, but GNAT does not know what kind of structure the address points to and therefore cannot run any checks about whether the referenced value of the parameter has been changed.

#### `pragma Preelaborate`

This tells the compiler that the package won't execute any code at elaboration time (i.e. before the main procedure starts executing). At elaboration time, the following constructs will execute:

- Initialization of library-level variables (this can be a function call)
- Initialization of tasks declared at library level (they may start executing before the main procedure does)
- Statements in a `begin ... end` block at library level

You generally should avoid these things if you don't need them. Use `pragma Preelaborate` wherever possible, it tells the caller that he can safely use the package without executing anything at elaboration time.

If something doesn't compile with one of these pragmas when you think it should, look into why it doesn't compile. It may help you discover problems with your package implementation or structure. Don't just drop the pragma when it doesn't compile. As the constraint affects possible constraints on any packages that depend on yours, you should always choose the strictest applicable pragma.

Comment: Does the behaviour of `Pure`, in regards to the requirement that subprograms don't produce side-effects, does it only apply to `functions` or does it effect `procedures` too? And by side-effects, are we talking local to the package? For example, a stream procedure that takes a `not null access Root_Stream_Type'Class`; surely the stream is altered by the proc so does that mean the package is not Pure, even if the stream is passed in from elsewhere?

Comment: `Root_Stream_Type` is limited, therefore calls to subroutines that take it as parameter may not be omitted. I added the relevant part of the ARM to my answer. But conceptually, yes, it's about side effects local to the package and the packages it depends on.

Answer (score 5):

[*Elaboration Order Handling in GNAT*](https://docs.adacore.com/gnat_ugn-docs/html/gnat_ugn/gnat_ugn/elaboration_order_handling_in_gnat.html) is a helpful guide. Ideally, the standard rules will suffice for most programs. The pragmas tell the compiler to substitute *your* elaboration order. They should be applied to solve specific problems, rather than used empirically.

Addendum: @ajb underscores an important distinction among the pragmas. The [article cited](https://docs.adacore.com/gnat_ugn-docs/html/gnat_ugn/gnat_ugn/elaboration_order_handling_in_gnat.html) agrees with the approach outlined in the question (bullets one and two): "Consequently a good rule is to mark units as `Pure` or `Preelaborate` if possible, and if this is not possible, mark them as `Elaborate_Body` if possible."  It goes on to discuss situations (bullet three) "where neither of these three pragmas can be used."

Comment: I think you're thinking of the Elaborate, Elaborate_All, and Elaborate_Body pragmas, whose purpose is to control the elaboration order.  That's all they do (except that Elaborate_Body tells the compiler that the package requires a body).  Pure and Preelaborate make some definite statements that a package does _not_ contain certain kinds of constructs.

Comment: @trashgod I had to avoid phrasing my question as "Can you elaborate on preelaborate?"